# Confused about defer in goroutines

Tags: go, synchronization, deadlock, goroutine

I came across the following code snippet that demonstrates the 'broadcast' functionality in sync.Cond. The snippet is as follows:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

func main() {
    type Button struct {
        Clicked *sync.Cond
    }
    button := Button{Clicked: sync.NewCond(&sync.Mutex{})}

    subscribe := func(c *sync.Cond, fn func()) {
        var goroutineRunning sync.WaitGroup
        goroutineRunning.Add(1)
        go func() {
            goroutineRunning.Done()
            c.L.Lock()
            defer c.L.Unlock()
            c.Wait()
            fn()
        }()
        goroutineRunning.Wait()
    }

    var clickRegistered sync.WaitGroup
    clickRegistered.Add(3)
    subscribe(button.Clicked, func() {
        fmt.Println("Maximizing window.")
        clickRegistered.Done()
    })
    subscribe(button.Clicked, func() {
        fmt.Println("Displaying annoying dialogue box!")
        clickRegistered.Done()
    })
    subscribe(button.Clicked, func() {
        fmt.Println("Mouse clicked.")
        clickRegistered.Done()
    })

    button.Clicked.Broadcast()

    clickRegistered.Wait()
}
```

The output is as follows:

```
Mouse clicked.
Maximizing window.
Displaying annoying dialogue box!
```

I changed the goroutine within the subscribe to defer the calling of 'Done' on the gorroutineRunning waitgroup after the goroutine is done executing. My thinking was that the waitgroup should decrement only after the go routine is done executing. So I changed the code as follows:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

func main() {
    ......
    subscribe := func(c *sync.Cond, fn func()) {
        var goroutineRunning sync.WaitGroup
        goroutineRunning.Add(1)
        go func() {
            //Adding the defer here
            defer goroutineRunning.Done()
            c.L.Lock()
            defer c.L.Unlock()
            c.Wait()
            fn()
        }()
        goroutineRunning.Wait()
    }

    ....
}
```

With the addition of the defer I get the following panic:

```
fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!

goroutine 1 [semacquire]:
sync.runtime_Semacquire(0xc0000b6028)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/sema.go:56 +0x42
sync.(*WaitGroup).Wait(0xc0000b6020)
        /usr/local/go/src/sync/waitgroup.go:130 +0x64
main.main.func1(0xc00009e040, 0xc0000b4030)
        /Users/go/concur/button.go:24 +0x91
main.main()
        /Users/go/concur/button.go:29 +0xf4

goroutine 18 [sync.Cond.Wait]:
runtime.goparkunlock(...)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:310
sync.runtime_notifyListWait(0xc00009e050, 0x0)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/sema.go:510 +0xf8
sync.(*Cond).Wait(0xc00009e040)
        /usr/local/go/src/sync/cond.go:56 +0x9d
main.main.func1.1(0xc0000b6020, 0xc00009e040, 0xc0000b4030)
        /Users/go/concur/button.go:21 +0xbb
created by main.main.func1
        /Users/go/concur/button.go:17 +0x83
exit status 2
```

Can somebody walk me through why adding the defer is causing the code to panic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original code releases the waitgroup as soon as the goroutine starts running. When the `subscribe` function returns, the goroutine is alive.

When you changed that to `defer goroutineRunning.Done()`, the goroutine starts, and stops at `c.Wait()`, because it is waiting for the condition variable broadcast. Since the goroutine is waiting there the `goroutineRunning.Done` is not called, and `subscribe` functions stops at the `goroutineRunning.Wait`. So the first time you call subscribe, it creates a goroutine that's waiting on a cond, subscribe itself starts waiting on the waitgroup. There are to goroutines (main and the one started by subscribe), both waiting for some event to happen, but there are no other goroutines running to make that event happen, so deadlock.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It does make sense. But then ideally, the goroutineRunning should not be needed, right? If it is simply getting set to done  before the go routine is done executing, theoretically it should not be needed, correct? Just trying to understand what function the goroutineRunning waitgroup serves in this case.

Comment: It is trying to make sure that all three goroutines are running before calling broadcast.

Comment: Ah! Makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: Actually I agree with the previous comment that the goroutineRunning WaitGroup does nothing useful (in the original code).  All it does is ensure that the go-routine starts but it could thence be imm. suspended, straight after the Done() call.

Comment: @AJR - That's what I thought but if I get rid of the goroutineRunning WaitGroup, I am getting intermittent deadlocks on runs. I am finding the semantics around wait to be somewhat confusing.

Comment: The waitgroup only ensures that the goroutine is running. It does not make sure that the goroutine is waiting on the condition variable. In that sense, the algorithm is broken.

Answer (score 1):

I think you were correct in identifying that there is something amiss with the use of the goroutineRunning WaitGroup.

I think the original code did not include the WaitGroup but whoever wrote the code found that there was a race condition where Broadcast() was called (on the sync.Cond variable) before the 3 go-routines had called Wait().  The use of goroutineRunning was an attempt to fix this but it does not avoid the race condition only makes it less likely to happen.  For example, if you put a sleep after goroutineRunning.Done() then you will get the same problem - Broadcast() called before the 3 go-routines are waiting.

To get back to your original question ... Moving goroutine.Done() forward (anywhere past the Wait call) will cause a deadlock since the c.Wait() call has to wait for the Broadcast() which can never come as the first subscribe() will never return until goroutineRunning.Done() is called (to unblock goroutineRunning.Wait()).

Moving goroutineRunning.Done() till before the c.Wait() is better but does not eliminate the race.

To fix the original code you need to put gorutineRunning.Done() after the call to c.L.Lock() and also lock the Broadcast().

```
    type Button struct {
        Clicked *sync.Cond
    }
    button := Button{ Clicked: sync.NewCond(&sync.Mutex{}) }

    subscribe := func(c *sync.Cond, fn func()) {
        var goroutineRunning sync.WaitGroup
        goroutineRunning.Add(1)
        go func() {
            c.L.Lock()
            defer c.L.Unlock()
            goroutineRunning.Done()  // *** moved
            c.Wait()
            fn()
        }()
        goroutineRunning.Wait()
    }

    var clickRegistered sync.WaitGroup
    clickRegistered.Add(3)
    subscribe(button.Clicked, func() {
        fmt.Println("Maximizing window.")
        clickRegistered.Done()
    })
    subscribe(button.Clicked, func() {
        fmt.Println("Displaying annoying dialog box!")
        clickRegistered.Done()
    })
    subscribe(button.Clicked, func() {
        fmt.Println("Mouse clicked.")
        clickRegistered.Done()
    })

    button.Clicked.L.Lock()     // *** new
    button.Clicked.Broadcast()
    button.Clicked.L.Unlock()   // *** new

    clickRegistered.Wait()
```

[BTW I accept that this is not the answer to your original question (and that the other answer should get the points) but I thought this worth mentioning.]

Comment: This is great! Thanks for putting this together. This explains a lot.